# Setting up project that uses Cedar for tests, Objective-C Realm and is testing swift Realm models

Tags: objective-c, swift, realm, cedar-bdd

I hope this question is seen and answered by someone from the Realm team

I have a project that uses Cedar to write BDD style tests.
I have a mixed project with Objective C and Swift files. 
Some of these swift files are for custom Realm models.
I use CocoaPods to install Realm to my project.

The recommended settings that I've seen so far are the following:

1. Use `Realm/Headers` in Podfile for Test targets and just `Realm` for main target - this solves the `+[RLMObjectBase ignoredProperties]: unrecognized selector sent to class` error.

My app builds and runs but now I get this `RLMObject subclasses with the same name cannot be included twice in the same target`

If I remove the swift objects from all of my test targets and leave them only on the main one, now I can't see them inside test files, which leads me to the next point

2. Use @testable in your swift files. That's a good advice if you're testing with a swift XCTest class, but it doesn't work with Cedar (or I don't know how to make it work)

So my question would be, is there any way I could make this setup work? What would be the exact steps?

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for the reply, I managed to find an answer in this fine gentleman's [blog post](http://www.trondbordewich.com/blog/tdd-in-mixed-objc-and-swift-projects/) :)

1. Make sure all your .swift files have Target Membership set only to your main target
2. As I mentioned in the question, in your Podfile add `Realm` for main target and `Realm/Headers` in your test targets
3. Check that all your test targets have `Build Settings -> Product Module Name` set to the same value as in your Main target
4. Final and **missing step** in my case, add the following path `$(CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR)/YourMainTargetName.build/DerivedSources` in your test targets `Build Settings -> Header Search Paths`

Do the final step for each test target, if you have multiple, and for each build configuration (ex: Alpha, Beta, Release) if you have multiple.

This also gives us the nice benefit of removing swift classes' membership from our test targets (just like for our Objective-C classes).

Now your tests should run, and Realm shouldn't throw exceptions at you.